# Clipboard colour depth - embedding image into an application

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, lotus-notes, print-screen, color-depth

I would like to paste screen-captures (obtained using the `Print Screen` key) into an old version of Lotus Notes (version 4.5.7). This does work, but the problem is that the images that are then embedded are *very large*, since (presumably) they are pasted as full-colour bitmaps at whatever colour depth the system uses, and this in turn makes the document very large.

In the past at my company I don't think this has been a problem (perhaps because we were using machines with lower colour depths, so the image got pasted at a lower quality? I'm not too sure about this).

Is there a way (using an option in Windows, an option in Lotus Notes (!), or a registry modification) to make the clipboard restrict its images to a lower bit depth - say, 256 colours, so that the embedded image is smaller? We are using Windows 7 and Vista.

[However - I don't know much about the Windows clipboard - I don't even know whether the clipboard *has* a concept of "the colour depth of the image I have", or whether it always uses the highest possible when pasting into an application, i.e. 32-bit or whatever]

Edit: I can't find anything that looks promising in the registry (searching for "Clip" or "Clipboard"), but it could be a Value which isn't present unless you need to change its default. I may be barking up the wrong tree here!

Edit 2: I tried writing a little C# program to copy the bitmap from the clipboard into a bitmap with a lower (16-bit) colour depth, and then set the clipboard image to that lower-colour image. However, when I then checked the colour depth of the updated image on the clipboard, it was still the original (32-bit) depth.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the entire screen?  You might try using greenshot or the win 7 built in snipping tool to capture smaller areas to paste in.

Are the emails only being sent internally or are you using external addressing?  External addressinig will often make the emails larger as they are converted from Notes rtf format to mime format for the internet.

Comment: Thanks. Good point about the Win 7 snipping tool - I was only recently shown that by a colleague. I'll have a look into Greenshot. As for the other question - it's staying within Notes (but they're documents, rather than emails, if there's a difference).

Comment: your app may be able to be modified to compress the images or something -- I've looked to see if there any normal options within attachment properties in email but haven't seen anything to reduce the actual size stored.